# Group by multiple keys and summarize/average multiple values of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and have ran into an issue with the below code.

I was looking for a way to group by multiple keys and summarize/average values of a list of dictionaries in Python. The below code (also located from previous question/response located here: [Group by multiple keys and summarize/average values of a list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674331/group-by-multiple-keys-and-summarize-average-values-of-a-list-of-dictionaries)) set me off on the right track but I am running into issues adding more field aggregation in the loop.

Say I have a list of dictionaries as seen below:

```
input = [
{'msn': '001', 'source': 'foo', 'status': '1', 'qty': 100, 'vol': 100},
{'msn': '001', 'source': 'bar', 'status': '2', 'qty': 200, 'vol': 200},
{'msn': '001', 'source': 'foo', 'status': '1', 'qty': 300, 'vol': 300},
{'msn': '002', 'source': 'baz', 'status': '2', 'qty': 400, 'vol': 100},
{'msn': '002', 'source': 'baz', 'status': '1', 'qty': 500, 'vol': 400},
{'msn': '002', 'source': 'qux', 'status': '1', 'qty': 600, 'vol': 100},
{'msn': '003', 'source': 'foo', 'status': '2', 'qty': 700, 'vol': 200}]
```

My code so far:

```
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(dict_list, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["msn", "source"], key))
    temp_dict["qty"] = sum(item["qty"] for item in grp)
    temp_dict["vol"] = sum(item["vol"] for item in grp)
    result.append(temp_dict)
```

Expected result was:

```
{'msn': '001', 'source': 'foo', 'qty': 400, 'vol': 400},
{'msn': '001', 'source': 'bar', 'qty': 200, 'vol': 200},
{'msn': '002', 'source': 'baz', 'qty': 200, 'vol': 500},
{'msn': '003', 'source': 'foo', 'qty': 900, 'vol': 200}]
```

Placement of `temp_dict["vol"] = sum(item["vol"] for item in grp)` within the for loop does not produce the desired results which is ultimately my issue.

How do I go about keeping the key, grouping as seen in the code while adding(appending) another field and its calculated value to the list?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What are the desired results? Could you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: I will try to clarify - The desired result would be to loop through the input, group based on the supplied key AND summarize each field (such as qty and vol) based on the key grouping. Ultimately I would like to append all the summarized details to each key grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "copy" `grp` if you want to iterate through it multiple times, `itertools.tee` can do that for you

```
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(dict_list, key = grouper), grouper):
    temp_dict = dict(zip(["msn", "source"], key))
    grp1, grp2 = tee(grp)
    temp_dict["qty"] = sum(item["qty"] for item in grp1)
    temp_dict["vol"] = sum(item["vol"] for item in grp2)
    result.append(temp_dict)
```

Comment: Paul - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I took what you provided, did some more research on tee() and came up with the below code that fits well with my project. Thanks - I have accepted your answer. New Code - grp1, grp2, grp3, grp4 = tee(grp,4)

Comment: @J.Ester Perfect. I'm myself only now learning itertools. Some things you can do with them are quite neat, aren't they?

Comment: Agreed - itertools is quite useful. The more I learn about Python the more I wish I would have started coding with it earlier in my career. Thanks again Paul for the help.