# Calculate average of list values grouped by second list

Tags: python

I didn't know how to better express myself in the title. Basically what I have is two lists:

```
a = ['A','B','A','C','D','C','A',...] 
b = [2,4,8,3,5,2,1,...]
```

`a` and `b` have the same length, `b` represents a value related to the letter in `a` .

Now I would like to calculate the Average value in `b` for each letter in `a`. So at the end I would have:

```
a = ['A','B','C','D',...]
b = [3.67, 4, 2.5, 5,...]
```

Is there a standard implementation for this in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674331/group-by-multiple-keys-and-summarize-average-values-of-a-list-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first perform a *group by*. We can do this for instance with a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

col = defaultdict(list)

for ai,bi in zip(a,b):
    col[ai].append(bi)
```

Now the dictionary `col` will look like:

```
>>> col
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'C': [3, 2], 'B': [4], 'D': [5], 'A': [2, 8, 1]})
```

and now we can calculate the average of all elements in the dictionary for instance like:

```
>>> {key:sum(vals)/len(vals) for key,vals in col.items()}
{'C': 2.5, 'B': 4.0, 'D': 5.0, 'A': 3.6666666666666665}
```

You can also convert it to two tuples by using `zip`:

```
a,b = zip(*[(key,sum(vals)/len(vals)) for key,vals in col.items()])
```

resulting in:

```
>>> a,b = zip(*[(key,sum(vals)/len(vals)) for key,vals in col.items()])
>>> a
('C', 'B', 'D', 'A')
>>> b
(2.5, 4.0, 5.0, 3.6666666666666665)
```

If you want to generate lists instead, you can convert them to lists:

```
a,b = map(list,zip(*[(key,sum(vals)/len(vals)) for key,vals in col.items()]))
```

This results in:

```
>>> a,b = map(list,zip(*[(key,sum(vals)/len(vals)) for key,vals in col.items()]))
>>> a
['C', 'B', 'D', 'A']
>>> b
[2.5, 4.0, 5.0, 3.6666666666666665]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe a cleaner way to do this would be to simply use a pandas groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(b,index=a)
a,b = (list(data.groupby(data.index)[0].mean().index),list(data.groupby(data.index)[0].mean()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array_a = np.array(a)
>>> array_b = np.array(b)
>>> avrg_of_a = np.average(array_b[array_a == 'A'])
>>> avrg_of_a
3.6666666666666665
>>> avrg_of_b = np.average(array_b[array_a == 'B']) 
4.0
```

You can generate a list use list comprehensions `[np.average(array_b[array_a == item]) for item in np.unique(array_a)]`

Comment: This is not generalized and doesn't provide results as requested by the OP.

Comment: Why this is not generalized?

Comment: You've specifically defined variables for each value in your array_a.

Comment: You still haven't provided the answer in the format requested by the OP.

Comment: I contend that your answer does not answer the question as asked by the OP -- you do not end up with results for a and b as requested.  See my answer or the selected answer for those that have answered the question as asked.