# Group and aggregate a list of dictionaries by multiple keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, unique

I have a list that includes dictionaries (`List[Dict, Dict, ...]`) , I would like to uniqify the list based on two keys, but I want to retain the value of another key in the dictionary to make sure I do not lose it by making a list in the key I want to retain. I am using Python for the code. If it is of any significance Python 3.x to be exact.

Let's assume I have the following list of dictionaries with three keys: `number`, `favorite`, and `color`. I want to uniqify the list elements using the keys `number` and `favorite`. However for the dictionaries that have the same values `number` and `favorite`, I'd like to add a list under the key `color` to make sure I have all the `color`s for the same combination of `number` and `favorite`. This list should also be unique since it shouldn't need the repeated `color`s for the same combination. However, if there is only one element for the key color in the final result, it should be a string and not a list.

```
lst = [
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'green'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'}]
```

Using the aforementioned uniqify, I would get the following result:

```
lst = [
    {'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': {'red', 'green'}},
    {'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': 'red'},
    {'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
]
```

Note that there is only one instance of `red` where the `number` is `1` and `favorite` is `False` even though it appeared twice in the list before it was uniqified. Also note that when there is only one element for the key `color` in the second dict, it is a string and not a list.

Comment: Are you interested in using `pandas` for this?

Comment: `{'red', 'green'}` This still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it basically is a list that serves as a value to the key `color` @Praind

Comment: Is it necessary to have a string instead of a list if there's only one element?

Comment: yes it is necessary, will edit question to include that detail. Thank you @Praind

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674331/group-by-multiple-keys-and-summarize-average-values-of-a-list-of-dictionaries and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066269/group-by-and-aggregate-the-values-of-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using pure python, you can do insert into an `OrderedDict` to retain insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for l in lst:
    d.setdefault((l['number'], l['favorite']), set()).add(l['color'])

[{'number': k[0], 'favorite': k[1], 'color': v.pop() if len(v) == 1 else v} 
    for k, v in d.items()]   
# [{'color': {'green', 'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': True, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': False, 'number': 2}]
```

---

This can also be done quite easily using the pandas `GroupBy` API:

```
import pandas as pd

d = (pd.DataFrame(lst)
       .groupby(['number', 'favorite'])
       .color
       .agg(set)
       .reset_index()
       .to_dict('r'))
d
# [{'color': {'green', 'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': {'red'}, 'favorite': True, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': {'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 2}]
```

If the condition of a string for a single element is required, you can use

```
[{'color': (lambda v: v.pop() if len(v) == 1 else v)(d_.pop('color')), **d_} 
     for d_ in d]
# [{'color': {'green', 'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': True, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': False, 'number': 2}]
```

Comment: What if we pass `.color` and `.number` both to the above solution. I have another use case where I need to pass two-column of the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

A solution in pure Python would be to use a `defaultdict` with a composite key. You could use that to merge your values.
Afterwards you can create a list again out of that dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict([])

for entry in lst:
    dct[(entry['number'], entry['favorite'])].append(entry['color'])

lst = [{'number': key[0], 'favorite': key[1], color: value if len(value) > 1 else value[0]}
    for key, value in dct.items()]
```

Comment: *composite key i guess?

Comment: @Vineeth Sai Indeed ;)

Comment: would this work even if there are more keys than the three mentioned, i.ei if you have a new key? @Praind

Comment: Of course, you just have to add them to the composite key. E.g.
`dct[(entry['number'], entry['favorite'], entry['otherKey'])].append(entry['color'])`

Comment: This would not retain order (unless python3.6), as the question seems to require.

Answer (score 2):

Or `groupby` of `itertools`:

```
import itertools
lst = [
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'green'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'}]
l=[list(y) for x,y in itertools.groupby(sorted(lst,key=lambda x: (x['number'],x['favorite'])),lambda x: (x['number'],x['favorite']))]
print([{k:(v if k!='color' else list(set([x['color'] for x in i]))) for k,v in i[0].items()} for i in l])
```

Output:

```
[{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': ['green', 'red']}, {'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': ['red']}, {'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': ['red']}]
```

Comment: Do you know that your solution won't work if the input list isn't already sorted (w.r.t. number and favorite)? Like if the list contained first dict element as number=1, and favorite=False, second as number=1, and favorite=True, and then number=1, and favorite=False.

Comment: Try with this input list: `lst = [
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'green'},
{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'},
{'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': 'red'}]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ordered dictionary with default `set` values.<sup>1</sup> Then iterate your list of dictionaries, using `(number, favorite)` as keys. This works since tuples are hashable and therefore permitted to be used as dictionary keys.

It's good practice to use a consistent structure. So, instead of having strings for single values and sets for multiple, use sets throughout:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

class DefaultOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, k):
        self[k] = set()
        return self[k]

d = DefaultOrderedDict()  # Python 3.7+: d = defaultdict(set)

for i in lst:
    d[(i['number'], i['favorite'])].add(i['color'])

res = [{'number': num, 'favorite': fav, 'color': col} for (num, fav), col in d.items()]

print(res)
# [{'color': {'green', 'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': {'red'}, 'favorite': True, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': {'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 2}]
```

If you insist on having different types depending on number of colours, you can redefine the list comprehension to use a ternary statement:

```
res = [{'number': num, 'favorite': fav, 'color': next(iter(col)) if len(col) == 1 else col} \
       for (num, fav), col in d.items()]

print(res)
# [{'color': {'green', 'red'}, 'favorite': False, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': True, 'number': 1},
#  {'color': 'red', 'favorite': False, 'number': 2}]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The point is noteworthy in Python versions prior to 3.7, where dictionaries are not guaranteed to be insertion ordered. With Python 3.7+, you can take advantage of insertion ordering and just use `dict` or a subclass of `dict` such as `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it,

I've built a `dict` first using a tuple as a composite key, Then made a new list out of that `dict`. You can write comprehensions to further reduce lines and optimize it, Hope it helps.

```
new_dict = {}

for item in lst:
    try: # if already exists then append to the list
        new_dict.get((item['number'], item['favorite']))
        new_dict[(item['number'], item['favorite'])].append(item['color'])
    except KeyError: # if it doesn't then create a new entry to that key
        new_dict[(item['number'], item['favorite'])] = [item['color']]


final_list = []
for k, v in new_dict.items(): # keep appending dicts to our list
    final_list.append({'number': k[0], 'favorite': k[1], 'color':set(v)})

print(final_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'number': 1, 'favorite': False, 'color': {'green', 'red'}}, {'number': 1, 'favorite': True, 'color': {'red'}}, {'number': 2, 'favorite': False, 'color': {'red'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine made the following function to solve this problem, without using any external libraries:

```
def uniqifyColors(l):
    for elem in l:
        for item in l:
            if elem['number'] == item['number'] and elem['favorite'] == item['favorite']:
                for clr in item['color']:
                    if clr not in elem['color']:
                        elem['color'].append(clr)
    return l
```

After using this Python function, he simply did a trivial uniqify to get the unique results from the list. It does not, however, keep a single color as a string, but rather a list with a single element.